# Does not display data from database at blade.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-8

i have this code in my blade.php file

```html
<table class="table table-success table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Password</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{$user->ID}}</th>
                <td>{{$user->username}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->password}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
</table>
```

and when i call my blade.php file to view a html page, i see only the emails from data.

[This is the view when i run a dd($user) command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVqt0.png)

[This is a Html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq32t.jpg)

Comment: You can `dd($user)` to see what it contains. The properties are case sensitive, so `$user->ID` should probably be `$user->id`, but that would depend on your schema.

Comment: i tried this method with dd($user) and the data are passing to my blade.php file.could be the name 'username' and 'password' the problem? I looked my database table and the name of column is the same which i use in my code

Comment: could you post your model (and possibly migration)? also, is it really wordpress? please dont add unrelated the tags for whatever reason.

Comment: its a laravel project in wordpress and i fecth my data from wordpress database.

Comment: Can you show one example of what `dd($user)` showed?

Comment: yes i have a picture in post!!

Comment: Okay, `ID` should be correct, but the other fields are `user_login`, `user_nicename`, `user_pass` (which you should never expose anyway) and `user_email`

Comment: i changed the fields with the names that you told me, but i have the same error.

Comment: You have an error, or it's just not showing the data? Can you show us what you're getting?

Comment: I have added a image in my post with the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got names wrong. Try this:

```
<table class="table table-success table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Password</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($users as $user){
        echo "<tr>
                <th scope='row'>".$user['ID']."</th>
                <td>".$user['user_login']."</td>
                <td>".$user['user_pass']."</td>
                <td>".$user['user_email']."</td>
            </tr>";}
     ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Psst. Objects, not arrays, and you've taken out the blade syntax, breaking the page